# Virtual Environment in Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

When we create a virtual environment is it good practice to keep, our virtual environment folder and our project folder inside the same root folder?
If I am not wrong then every project has its own virtual environment so how can we remember which project use which virtual environment if we have created too many virtual environments for many projects?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you maintain a virtual environment per project. In this way, each project will be able to keep the packages you require in different versions without worrying about generating conflicts when installing or updating them.

For example, if you started a project in Django last year using version 2.2, to start another project you should create a new virtual environment in its root that allows you to install the most recent Django version.

Something like this.

```
/project_1
    /venv
/project_2
    /venv
```

Comment: When we create a virtual environment is it good practice to keep, our virtual environment folder and our project folder inside the same root folder? Or should we keep our virtual environment folder inside our project folder?